# Generating random samples from a given distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, simulation, random-generation

What are the different methods by which we can generate random samples from the existing distribution which are computationally efficient?

One of the common methods given in statistics text is by applying a transformation called the inversion method. We start with a Uniform(0,1) distribution from which we can pick an arbitrary number, and then use the inverse of the CDF of the distribution (its quantile function) to find the member of the desired distribution corresponding to the randomly chosen number between 0 and 1.

What other methods exist for doing the same?

Comment: one issue with the inversion method is that if the quantile function isn't available in closed form (i.e. you can't invert it to get the member of the desired distribution as a simple function of the randomly chosen number between 0 and 1), then you have to numerically solve to get the inverse. So simple textbook examples using the inversion method don't necessarily generalize to more complex distributions.

Comment: There are books largely or wholly about this: e.g. Morgan, _Elements of Simulation,_ or Devroye, _Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation_.

Comment: Generating samples efficiently from general distributions is not possible.

Comment: @ziggystar I'm curious: could you provide some support for this provocative assertion, such as an example of a distribution where "efficient" sampling is impossible?

Comment: Take the uniform distribution over the solutions to a boolean formula. Coming up with any solution is NP-complete; generating one uniformly is supposedly even harder. Generating samples from a Markov network (or MRF) is intractable in general, too. I admit that these are non-trivial, multivariate distributions, but they are "distributions". Also I suppose that there are ways to encode any multivariate distribution over discrete variables into a single continuous univariate distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Other methods include [accept-reject methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) and [Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) (MCMC) methods. Note that the method described in the question is part of the so-called [inverse transformation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling_method). There exists other ad-hoc simulation methods for specific distributions (e.g., the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) for univariate normal distribution).